# Display prediction on a webpage through flask

Tags: html, machine-learning, flask

I am trying to display the prediction that has been generated from the features I have provided in the dropdown menu on my web page. I have trained, tested and picked the best ML model. I have created flask route so that when you select id from the dropdown menu it automatically spits out the prediction, this part works. I have not been able, however, to display it on the webpage.

````
def features(patientID):
    """Returns list of features for given patient ID"""

    # Create list of feature names
    feature_names = ["Radius (worst)", "Texture (worst)", "Perimeter (worst)",\
        "Area (worst)", "Smoothness (worst)", "Compactness (worst)", \
        "Concavity (worst)", "Concave points (worst)", "Symmetry (worst)", \
        "Fractal dimension (worst)"]

    row = int(patientID) - 19000

    # Load dataset from sklearn and set X to feature array
    X = load_breast_cancer().data
    feature_values = X[row]

    # Select only features to be displayed
    feature_values = feature_values[20:]

    # Create dictionary of keys feature names and values
    features_dict = dict(zip(feature_names, feature_values))

    return jsonify(features_dict)


@app.route("/analyze/<patientID>")
def analyze(patientID):
    """Submit data to calculator"""

    # Translate patient ID to row
    row = (int(patientID) - 19000)

    # Load features, model, and scaler 
    X = load_breast_cancer().data
    model = load("rf_model.joblib")
    scaler = load("scaler.out")

    # Get features for selected row and scale
    row = np.array([row])
    feature_values = X[row]
    feature_values = scaler.transform(feature_values)

    # Predict diagnosis
    prediction = model.predict(feature_values)
    if prediction == 0:
        diagnosis = "Benign"
    else:
        diagnosis = "Malignant"

    # return jsonify(diagnosis)
    return render_template("calculator.html",diagnosis=diagnosis)```

# HTML code below.

      <div class="demo-container">
          <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-x align-middle grid-margin-x" id="app">
              <div class="cell large-6 text-center">
                <h3>Select Patient ID</h3>
                <form>
                <select id="selPatient" onchange="selectPatient(this.value)"></select>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Measurement</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </form>
                <button type="submit" class="large button expanded" id="analyze">Analyze</button>
              </div>
              <div class="cell large-6">
                <div class="result text-center">
                  <h3 id="diagnosis">Diagnosis: {{ diagnosis }} </h3>
                </div>
````

Comment: you have write function in your html file in oreder recieve the responce of parameter response in js section for detail info you can cheack on Flask official docs.Thank You!

Comment: That part is probably handled on the frontend using JavaScript. Can you please add your JavaScript code to your question?

Comment: Thak you @Lucas Hild I figured this out, Javascript code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
  /**
    /* Creates dropdown menu of patient ID's
    */

  // Create list of patient ID's
  var patientList = [];
  for (var i = 19000; i <= 19010; i++) {
    patientList.push(i);
  }

  // Add first dropdown item
  d3.select("#selPatient")
    .append("option")
    .text("");

  // Create dropdown menu of patientID's to populate the select options
  patientList.forEach(patientID => {
    d3.select("#selPatient")
      .append("option")
      .text(patientID)
      .property("value", patientID);
  });
}

function submitdropdownvalue(newvalue) {
  d3.select("#analyze").property("value", newvalue);
}

function selectPatient(patientID) {
  /**
    /* Populates form with features from selected patient
    /* @param {string}    patientID    ID of selected patient 
    /* patient in feature array
    */

  // Saving the table and results as variables
  var table = d3.select("tbody");
  var resultDisplay = d3.select("#diagnosis");

  // Clear values for existing feature table and diagnosis
  table.html("");
  resultDisplay.html("&nbsp;");

  var featuresURL = `/features/${patientID}`;
  var analysisURL = `/analyze/${patientID}`;

  // Fetch dictionary of the name of the features and corresponding values
  d3.json(featuresURL).then(function(patientFeatures) {
    // For each feature, enter the feature name and the feature value into a row
    Object.entries(patientFeatures).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      var tableRow = table.append("tr");
      tableRow.append("td").text(key);
      tableRow.append("td").text(value);
    });
  });

  // Fetch results and display in #diagnosis
  d3.json(analysisURL).then(function(results) {
    resultDisplay.html(results);
  });
}

// Create drop down
createDropdown();
```